# What's the point of using Spark on a single system?

Tags: apache-spark

I found people installing Spark IDE on their personal laptops. I think Spark is not built for centralized processing, rather it needs group of nodes (cluster) to establish parallelism and fast processing.

What's the point of using Spark on a single system? Because its working is based on multi node distributed system. Please explain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Testing functionality locally while developing, usually on small "toy" data sets.